# Getting EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION, path not clear

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, ios6, crash

Trying to figure out what could cause this to blow up, but cannot come up with any solid arguments.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000000f5904604
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   WebCore                         0x00073528 WebCore::RenderView::computeLogicalHeight() + 0
1   WebCore                         0x0006ba68 WebCore::RenderBlock::layoutBlock(bool, int) + 1548
2   WebCore                         0x0006b15a WebCore::RenderBlock::layout() + 38
3   WebCore                         0x0006afe6 WebCore::RenderView::layout() + 478
4   WebCore                         0x0006599a WebCore::FrameView::layout(bool) + 1554
5   WebCore                         0x00095ed8 WebCore::FrameView::updateLayoutAndStyleIfNeededRecursive() + 92
6   WebKit                          0x0000af5c -[WebHTMLView(WebPrivate) viewWillDraw] + 76
7   CoreFoundation                  0x00048616 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 174
8   CoreFoundation                  0x00048616 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 174
9   CoreFoundation                  0x00048616 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 174
10  CoreFoundation                  0x00048616 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 174
11  WebCore                         0x00095c30 WebCore::TileCache::prepareToDraw() + 60
12  QuartzCore                      0x00003924 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 456
13  QuartzCore                      0x00004858 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 12
14  QuartzCore                      0x0000423e CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 234
15  QuartzCore                      0x0000404c CA::Transaction::commit() + 312
16  UIKit                           0x0000c8e6 _afterCACommitHandler + 122
17  CoreFoundation                  0x000976ca __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 18
18  CoreFoundation                  0x000959bc __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 272
19  CoreFoundation                  0x00095d12 __CFRunLoopRun + 738
20  CoreFoundation                  0x00008eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
21  CoreFoundation                  0x00008d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
22  GraphicsServices                0x000052e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
23  UIKit                           0x000572fc UIApplicationMain + 1116
24  MyApp                       0x000c7eea -[viewController displayControllers:] (ViewController.m:45)
```

And this is line 45.

```
[_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(100,44 * 3)];
```

_scrollView is an IBOutlet.

Comment: Have you tried the debugging methods on the answer mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815100/exc-bad-instruction-at-performselector?

Comment: Unfortunately it was a reported crash log, I wasn't able to reproduce it myself while debugging it.